# retrieving the name of a user created table type programatically

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sysobjects

Running a select on `sys.objects` for a type I created:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[IntListType] AS TABLE(
[ID] [int] NULL) 


Select * From sysObjects Where Name Like '%listtype%'
```

I get the names back as follows:

```
name : TT_IntListType_2E4CAB33
xtype : TT
type : TT
```

and stuff.

How do I get the access to the original name of `dbo.IntListType`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query [`sys.table_types`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510623.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the sys.types table.

```
select * from sys.types
 where name like '%listtype%'
```

Comment: cool. Feel free to upvote our answers if they were helpful then! :)